# Azure Backup failing with errors 80780049 and 8078010E

Tags: backup, azure, system-state

We use the Microsoft Azure Recovery Services (MARS) agent to back up system state of a Windows Server 2012 R2 server.

These backups started failing with the following errors:

```
Unable to perform the operation as Windows Server Backup job failed with error message: None of the items included in backup were backed up.
 Detailed error: Copy of the files failed.
 HResult:80780049 DetailedHResult:8078010E
```

I found nothing relevant online for these particular errors, hence this post.

I have:

1. Found https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4053355/microsoft-azure-recovery-services-agent-system-state-backup-failure which says to review the WSB Failure Logs but that option is not present for some reason.
2. Found that `vssadmin list writers` is reporting that all VSS writers are stable.
3. Found that C: had 23.3 GB free of 99.6 GB.
4. Tried increasing the Shadow Copy limit on C: from 8156 MB to 20480 MB (20 % of total) but that didn't make a difference.
5. Found events logged by `volsnap` around the time of the backups saying `The oldest shadow copy of volume C: was deleted to keep disk space usage for shadow copies of volume C: below the user defined limit.`
6. Tried increasing the Shadow Copy limit on C: again from 20480 MB to 30720 MB but that didn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that our RMM system was reporting the following around the time of the backup failing:

1. `We have observed that the free disk space on <server hostname>\C: volume  is 1939 MB, which is below the threshold set.`
2. `Free Disk Space for C: drive on <server hostname> is now 28106 MB.`

I increased the storage capacity of C: from 100 GB to 125 GB which has resolved the problem.